# ruby rest_client put request doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby, put, rest-client

I send PUT request to some service with RestClient gem. I do it like:

```
RestClient.put('http:/app.com/resource/:id.json', { app_token: 'xxx', resource: { status: 'NNN' }})
```

But the answer JSON is empty (doesn't return what I need). If I send the request like this:

```
RestClient.put('http:/app.com/resource/:id.json?app_token=XXX&resource[status]=NNN', {})
```

then all is OK (JSON is normal). What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

---

P.S. Log:

1) RestClient.put "http:/app.com/resource/:id.json", "app_token=XXX&resource[status]=NNN", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-Length"=>"73", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

# => 200 OK | application/json 12 bytes ***(empty JSON)***

2) RestClient.put "http:/app.com/resource/:id.json?app_token=XXX&resource[status]=NNN", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"

# => 200 OK | application/json 37 bytes ***(valid JSON)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doc I think it should be written as:

```
RestClient.put('http:/app.com/resource/:id.json', nil,{params: { app_token: 'xxx', resource: { status: 'NNN' }}})
```

See https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#query-parameters

Comment: tyied to, but get the same result :(

Comment: sorry, for a post, did you try this:
    RestClient.put('http:/app.com/resource/:id.json', nil,{params: { app_token: 'xxx', resource: { status: 'NNN' }}})

(I've updated my answer), just add the nil or "" in the payload

Comment: Yes, this is nice! Only one problem: rest_client generates next request:

 RestClient.put "http:/app.com/resource/:id.json?app_token=XXX&&resource=%7B%3Astatus%3D%3E%22NNN%22%7D", "", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-Length"=>"0", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: It means, that RestClient send next parameters: `resource={:status=>"NNN"}`

Comment: I can send `RestClient.put('http:/app.com/resource/:id.json', nil,{params: { app_token: 'xxx', 'resource[status]' => 'NNN' }})`, but it is some monkey patch :|

Comment: no, the second parameter is the payload of the post. Usually, if you do a post request, that's because you "post" something and this is usually not empty , this make sense...

Comment: I mean that `'resource[status]' => 'NNN'` is the monkey patch. I wanna clear syntax like simple hash, not the strings...

Comment: ah I see..... there should be something in rails somewhere to do this, not sure if your app is using rails?

Comment: .to_query does the job, but it's add by rails.

Exemple: {params:{a:1}}.to_query 

returns
    "params%5Ba%5D=1"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this one out? Much cleaner syntax.

```
@options = { 
    params: { 
        app_token: 'xxx', 
        resource: { 
            status: 'NNN'
        }
    } 
}

RestClient.put("http:/app.com/resource/:id.json", @options)
```